# Migrate Azure classic VM to ARM. error in Virtual Network validation

Tags: azure, migration, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I tried to migrate Azure classic ASM virtual machine to ARM by following [the instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-migration-classic-resource-manager).

At the beginning of **Step 5**, the validation command in Option 1;

```
$validate = Move-AzureService -Validate -ServiceName $serviceName `
  -DeploymentName $deploymentName -CreateNewVirtualNetwork
$validate.ValidationMessages
```

gives following error.

> ResourceType       : Deployment
>
> ResourceName       : database-vm
>
> Category           : Error
>
> Message: Deployment database-vm in HostedService database-vm belongs to Virtual
>    Network Group database-east-asia DatabaseNetwork. Please migrate Virtual Network Group database-east-asia DatabaseNetwork to migrate this HostedService database-vm.
>
> VirtualMachineName:

Option 2 validation also gives same error.

This kind of error message [cannot be found in the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-migration-errors). I also try to validate VirtualNetwork command as below in order to migrate virtual network firstly.

```
Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Validate -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName
```

But, the command gives below error.

> OperationId        : 8b66a5c9-a657-3a91-af8d-2c29ceXXXX9f
>
> Result             : Validation failed.  Please see ValidationMessages for details
>
> ValidationMessages : {DatabaseNetwork}

How to resolve this issue?

**+ Append**

I applied below arguments to do `Move-AzureService` in [Option 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-migration-classic-resource-manager#step-5-run-commands-to-migrate-your-iaas-resources).

```
$existingVnetRGName = "database-east-asia"
$vnetName = "Group database-east-asia DatabaseNetwork"
$subnetName = "default"
```

I changed `$vnetName` argument to `DatabaseNetwork` but no luck.

I can see very long `Group database-east-asia DatabaseNetwork` in classic portal. Note that VM and Vnet does not in same resource group. I don't know this is matter.

The error message is nothing more detail than above. I found `VirtualMachineName` is empty in error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please post the detailed ValidationMessages of your second command?

According to the error message, the VNET named "DatabaseNetwork" can not be migrated for some reasons.

Normally, this error message is caused by unsupported features configured on the VNET.

- Endpoint ACLs.
- Virtual network gateways (Azure ExpressRoute Gateways, Application
  gateway).
- Virtual networks using VNet Peering.
- Traffic Manager profiles.

You need to disable these features and then migrate the VNET. After the migration, you can enable it back on Resource Mode.

==========================================================

Update:

1. To get the detailed ValidationMessages of your second command, please run the following commands:

   `$validate=Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Validate -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName
   $validate.ValidationMessages`
2. To migrate a VM connected to a VNET, we just need to migrate the VNET, the VM will be migrated with the VNET automatically.

Comment: I realized that gateway is configured; http://stackoverflow.com/q/40716166/361100 Let me mitigate my problem firstly and then try your answer. thanks.

Comment: I appended my input arguments and edited error message a little.

Comment: @Youngjae The resource id is not necessary. I just need the detailed  ValidationMessages of "Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Validate -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName". It does not contain any ID. According to your another post answered by me, it seems that there is a gateway in the VNET and you have delete it successfully. Please validate the VNET again. If the validation still fails, please post the detailed ValidationMessages in your original post.

Comment: // thanks. I ended up by following this post, https://www.petri.com/migrating-azure-vms-classic-service-management-resource-manager but one mysterious thing is that, I didn't do `Move-AzureService` but vm is already moved after I commit `Move-AzureVirtualNetwork` successfully.

Comment: @Youngjae It's a by design behavior, I've stated it in my update. "2.To migrate a VM connected to a VNET, we just need to migrate the VNET, the VM will be migrated with the VNET automatically."

Comment: Thanks. I now understand what you're saying.