# Disable VPN gateway in Azure classic VM virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

While [trying Azure VM migration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40654034/361100) from ASM to ARM, I realized that "Configure point-to-site connectivity" is *checked* (so we can say VPN gateway is configured) to the network settings even though I does not have any connection to the VPN gateway.

`The network is in use` description is displayed in old portal and it still remains after deallocating the VM. Unchecking then save action gives failure as expected by using PowerShell command and Portal.

How to disable this setting? Do I have to recreate VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the VPN gateway on the VNET? If yes, you need to delete the gateway first.

You are able to delete the gateway via portal or powershell.

To get the GatewayId, please run the command **Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway**.

Then we are able to delete the gateway with command **Remove-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway -GatewayId** *your_gateway_id*

[image: delete gateway]

Comment: Thanks. unchecking `Configure point-to-site connectivity` throws internal error right after I deleted the gateway, but it successfully works after several minutes :)